# python module layout

Tags: python, python-module

I'm just starting to get to the point in my python projects that I need to start using multiple packages and I'm a little confused on exactly how everything is supposed to work together. What exactly should go into the `__init__.py` of the package? Some projects I see just have blank inits and all of their code are in modules in that package. Other projects implement what seems to be the majority of the package's classes and functions inside the init.

Is there a document or style guide or something that describes what the python authors had in mind for the use of packages and the `__init__` file and such?

**Edit:**
I know the point of having the `__init__.py` file in the simplest sense that it makes a folder a package. But why would I put a function there instead of a module in that same folder(package)?

Answer (score 8):

`__init__.py` can be empty, but what it really does is make sure Python treats your directories correctly, provide any initialization you might need for when your package is imported (configuring the environment or something along those lines), or defining `__all__` so that Python knows what to do when someone uses `from package import *`.

Most everything you need to know is described in the [docs on Packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages). [Dive Into Python also has a piece on packaging.](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/packages.html)

Answer (score 1):

You already know, I guess that __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages.

1. In the above model __init__.py can remain empty.
2. You can can also execute initialization code for the package.
3. You can also set the __all__ variable.

[Edit: learnings]
When you do "from package import item", or "from package import *", then the variable __all__ can be used to import selected packages.

See : http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: `__init__.py`, `__all__`. Double underscores

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: Thanks. Yes, Edit problems. My answer is the same as yours and I did not see it before posting mine.

Comment: For `from package import item`, the variable `__all__` does not control what gets exposed.  If `item` is a module or a subpackage, and you are on Windows, `__all__` might control the capitalisation of `item`, but it does not control what you can access.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: __all__ is intended primarily for wildcard imports. It does not attempt to provide any form of access-control. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package for the details.